# How to disable Gnome from making Documents/ Video/ in HOME?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

Everytime I login graphically on Ubuntu 11.10 it creates

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
```

in my `$HOME`.

How do I disable Nautilus (?) from doing that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sed -i s/enabled=True/enabled=False/g /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf
```

Comment: Indeed. Please note you can also use `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` in case you don't have root access or if you need a per-user configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to also change the Chrome/Firefox/Slack etc download path. By default they point to the `Downloads` folder in your home and are automatically created if missing.